# Pyspark read existing records using kafka

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have connected my Postgres DB to Kafka to read new records in the table and push them to elasticsearch.
The DB already has a few records and when I connect kafka to the DB those records are visible in the kafka topic (using `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic postgres.public.table --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --from-beginning`).

But using the following code snippet, I am able to read only the new records that come in the table.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    if es.indices.exists('test-index'):
           es.indices.delete('test-index')
    
    es.indices.create('test-index')

    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    print(brokers)
    print(topic)
    kStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic],{"metadata.broker.list": brokers,
                       'group.id':'ozy-group', 
                       'fetch.message.max.bytes':'15728640',
                       'auto.offset.reset':'largest'})
    lines = kStream.map(lambda x: x[1])
    lines.count().map(lambda x:'profiles in this batch: %d' % x).pprint()

    lines.foreachRDD(RDDfromKafkaStream)
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

How do I read the existing records in the table as well?

Answer (score 0):

`'auto.offset.reset':'smallest'` will make the consumer read data that already exists, not data that comes in after you start the consumer

Sidenote: You should use Structured Streaming instead

Comment: Do you mean it will then read only the data already present, and will ignore the new incoming records? For my use case, I want both types of records to be included. I'll check about structured streaming as well.

Comment: No, no. The offset will just start at the earliest position of the topic and continue forward, then wait for new data. There's no "end" of a Kafka topic that'll stop a consumer. The code you posted in the question only starts reading from "after" the most recent message on the topic.